# MySQL breaking a large table into smalller related tables

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to break a large MySQL table into smaller related tables?

for instance imagine the table:

```
x_data--
id | offer_price | offer_text | free_gift | free_gift_category | model_name | model_description | tariff_name | tariff_rental | tariff_minutes | tariff_texts | tariff_data | retailer_name | retailer_description
```

is it possible to split this out into separate tables and build relationships so the resulting tables look like:

```
offers--
id | offer_price | offer_text | free_gift_id | model_id | tariff_id | retailer_id

free_gifts-- 
id | free_gift | free_gift_category_id

free_gift_categories--
id | free_gift_category

models--
id | name | description

tariffs--
id | name | rental | minutes | texts | data

retailers--
id | name | description
```

i.e can I do an insert on a sub select or join?

something like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO retailers (name,description) 
    (SELECT retailer_name, retailer_description FROM x_data) as retailer, 
    (SELECT MAX(id) as retailer_id FROM retailers) as retailer_id,
     INSERT INTO tariffs (name, rental, minutes, texts, data) as tariffs, ...."
```

if this is possible how would I go about it?

Comment: IT's possible, but you need to lookup the proper syntax for the insert statement. Specifically, INSERT ... SELECT.

Comment: If you mean that you want to normalize one table into multiple tables, the issue you will have to do outside MySQL is to get the keys of rows inserted so you can populate the foreign keys. That will require inserting rows in the child tables, getting the most recent key inserted, and then populating the parent table.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I want to avoid if at all possible looping through each row in order to build the relationships the x_data table can contain up to 6 million rows. Do you know what terminology would I search for in order to get the proper syntax ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to loop through the rows in order to normalize the data. Good thing is, it should be a one-time exercise if you start using the normalized tables once it's done. Part of the process will be to eliminate child duplicates. It's not an easy process, but pat of the painful consequence of not having a db properly designed to start with.

Comment: @SloanThrasher that's a shame the import is a csv and it comes as one huge file I currently read the csv in chunks and import directly into the child tables and build the relationships up as I go, I was hoping dumping the lot into a single table and using mysql might be less intensive then the file system - it still might be ?

Comment: Not likely. The problem is with the foreign keys. There just isn't a simple way to get them, and to de-dup child rows without stepping through the rows. You could either do in php or SQL, but php will be a lot faster.

Comment: @SloanThrasher so you think I am better sticking with my current implementation of looping through the csv using php vs looping through mysql using php I can chunk / paginate either, I just always thought using the filesystem was a bit more memory intensive. What I have got works I am just looking at ways to improve things the data comes in that format sadly I have no control over that.

Comment: I don't see that you have any choice. There are ways to optimize, for example, built an array of the child values so you don't have to do a query to check if they already exist.